# How to use wp_terms_checklist() on front end

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

Getting a Fatal Error using `wp_terms_checklist()` in one of my advanced search form in Front End.

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function `wp_terms_checklist()`

With [search I got](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/undefined-function-on-wp_category_checklist#post-4616616) that it's creating problem because the function is for *admin panel use only*, BTW *not* deprecated.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'descendants_and_self'  => 0,
    'selected_cats'         => false,
    'popular_cats'          => false,
    'walker'                => null,
    'taxonomy'              => 'mytaxonomy',
    'checked_ontop'         => true
);
wp_terms_checklist( 0, $args );
?>
```

But if I need a similar thing in my front end. How can I achieve that? Is that possible in current flow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just include it in your `functions.php`:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    include ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php';
}
```

Or better (as suggested by @Lance Cleveland in the comments):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_terms_checklist' ) ) {
    include ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php';
}
```

Comment: I prefer a function-specific test versus the more generic is_admin() when including code to support something like this.

if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_terms_checklist' ) ) versus if ( ! is_admin() ) is more explicit and can avoid some unnecessary overhead depending on the code structure.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit the answer.